# How to search a specific field in a database

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I want the user to be able to choose from a dropdown Combobox listing some of the fields of the database, then below enter a search term and all then all the results that meet the query be displayed in the dbgrid. I'm not sure how to link the current value of the ComboBox into the sql statement. I tried using this

```
begin
    with ADOQuery do begin
      Close;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add ('SELECT * FROM List WHERE combobox1.text =' +   QuotedStr (Asearchterm.Text));
      Open;
```

And it doesn't work. The error i'm getting is "The parameter combobox1.text has no default value". Any ideas?

Comment: I assume `combobox1.text` is the value from your combo box, in which case it needs to not be part of the string.

Comment: I'm a little confused but do you mean not part of that sql line? I tried setting combobox1 to another variable and putting that in there but it still didnt't work

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not a good error description. Never. Add a proper error message you're getting from a database engine.

Comment: I was in a bit of rush and I knew this answer would be something simple but I agree I should have given the proper error. I will next time.

Comment: Never thought of it like that. Added it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to use the combobox1 text value as part of the sql statement, you'd set up the sql string along the lines of

```
'SELECT * FROM List WHERE [' + combobox1.text + '] = ''' + QuotedStr(Asearchterm.Text) + ''''
```

is probably what you're looking for.  I added the extra quotes around the QuotedStr because I'm guessing that the filter is not always going to be numeric values.  This will work for numeric as well as non-numeric values.

Comment: Don't build queries by appending user-entered values. Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: true, this simple solution is prone to SQL injection.  You would want to do some replace statements to make sure there aren't any single quotes or other risky characters in the search term, but I figured that's what the "QuotedStr" method was doing

Comment: Also if you're still here, how would I refresh the table as the user tries to search for something else as the table appears blank if I try and search for something different. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why the table would be blank, though this solution requires that the database gets queried with the SQL string each time the values are changed.  What can help with debugging dynamic SQL scenarios like this is outputting the SQL string to make sure there's nothing unexpected in it.

Comment: Yeah I must have entered something wrong in, it's working perfectly now, cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

instead of 'combobox1.text'  you have to put actual column name that you are looking for. And you can use `LIKE` keyword and some wildcards. something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table WHERE 'column' LIKE '%YOUR_SEARCH_TEXT%';
```

That was for a search...if you want to find exact string then you have to use `=` operator instead of LIKE

[More info here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)